# Is it necessary that $a\ge b$ to $h(n)=\sum\limits_{d^a|n}f(\frac n{d^a})g(\frac n{d^b})$ be multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative and $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with $a\ge b$. We can prove that $h(n)=\sum\limits_{d^a|n}f(\frac n{d^a})g(\frac n{d^b})$ is multiplicative as follows. Let $(m,n)=1$. Then we have

$$h(m)h(n)=\sum_{c^a|m}f(\frac m{c^a})g(\frac m{c^b})\sum_{d^a|n}f(\frac n{d^a})g(\frac n{d^b})\\
=\sum_{c^a|m\\d^a|n}f(\frac m{c^a})g(\frac m{c^b})f(\frac n{d^a})g(\frac n{d^b})\\
=\sum_{t^a|mn}f(\frac{mn}{t^a})g(\frac{mn}{t^b})=h(mn).$$

Thus, It seems that we didn't use $a\ge b$. But Apostol's number theory book has stated this problem for $a\ge b$. So I want to know if $a\ge b$ is necessary? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ensures that $d^b$ divides $n$ in the definition of $h$, so that $g$ is evaluated only where it is defined, i.e. at integers.

Comment: But if for some $d$, $d^b$ doesn't divide $n$, then we can remove that term in the sum. Can't we?

Comment: @user547800 I don't understand what you mean, only the $d$ such that $d^a$ divide $n$ appear in the sum but if $b > a$ then it is possible for $d^a$ to divide $n$ but not $d^b$. In this case, $n/d^b$ is not an integer and $g$ is only defined on integers, which is a problem.